# Get the maximum value of values for each category in SQL(oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group

Let us say we have the current table of subjects and marks of each students in that subject.

Table: Grades

```
Math:    ANDY  80
Math:    RYAN  70
Math:    SARAH 95 
Science: RYAN  60
Science: ANDY  90
Science: SARAH 75
```

I want to write a query to get the name of the subject, who has the highest mark, and what is it.

the output of the query should be as the following:

```
Math    SARAH 95
Science ANDY  90
```

what would be the sql (in oracle) to get this desired output? preferably without using a windows function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytical function `rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select g.*, rank() over(partition by subject order by mark desc) rn
    from grades
) t
where rn = 1
```

In the subquery, the analytical function ranks each record by descending `mark`  within groups having the same `subject`. Then, the outer query filters the top record per group. If there are ties, they are all returned (you can use `row_number()` to avoid that, or add another sorting criteria to the `order by` clause).

Comment: thank you for your time. really. but is there a different approach that doesn't use windows functions. like nesting multiple counts or conditions?

Comment: @A.Nassar: there are alternatives, but they will probably be less efficient. Why don't you want to use analytical functions?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can do this with aggregation and `keep`:

```
select subject,
       max(mark),
       max(student) keep (dense_rank first order by mark desc)
from grades
group by subject;
```

Note:  This only keeps one student per subject, even when there are ties.  You could use `listagg()` to get all of them.